# How to attach an email as object in a cell using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code to attach files in an excel sheet, it works but files are placed on top of other. How do i get the files placed individually in each cell?

```
   For Each elAtt In AttachList
    Set MyAtt = Bug.Attachments.Item(elAtt.ID)
    MyAtt.Load True, ""
    'MsgBox MyAtt.Filename
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = MyAtt.Filename
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = MyAtt.Description
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=MyAtt.Filename, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=40, Top:=40, Width:=20, Height:=10
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = Left(MyAtt.Filename, InStrRev(MyAtt.Filename, "\") - 1)
    'theFileName = MyAtt.Filename
    'thePath = Left(theFileName, InStrRev(theFileName, "\") - 1)
    Set MyAtt = Nothing
i = i + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the structure of this line of your code:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=MyAtt.Filename, Link:=False, _
         DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=40, Top:=40, Width:=20, Height:=10
```

which refers to the `Add method` syntax of `OLEObjects collection`:

```
expression.Add(ClassType, FileName, Link, _
         DisplayAsIcon, IconFileName, IconIndex, IconLabel, Left, Top, Width, Height)
```

You need to change `Left` and `Top` parameters for `.Add method`. The solution could be as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=MyAtt.Filename, Link:=False, _
          DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Cells(i, 4).Left, Top:=Cells(i, 4).Top, _
          Width:=20, Height:=10
```